# Leak when assigning regions of a UIImage to UIImageView animationImages

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-leaks, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a UIImage category method that does this:

```
- (UIImage *)subimageInRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([self CGImage], rect);
    UIImage *answer = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return answer;
}
```

And another category method that will dice a short, wide image (like a film strip) into N more evenly proportioned images (like frames), as follows:

```
- (NSArray *)subimagesHorizontally:(NSInteger)count {

    NSMutableArray *answer = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:count];
    CGFloat width = self.size.width / count;
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, width, self.size.height);

    for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        [answer addObject:[self subimageInRect:rect]];
        rect = CGRectOffset(rect, width, 0.0);
    }
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:answer];
}
```

These are assigned the highlightedAnimationImages property of a UIImageView, several of which are contained in a table.  (and handled in the standard fashion.. storyboarded prototype cells, tagged and accessed in the datasource using [cell viewWithTag:...]).

It functions fine, but leaks reports a leak as soon as the table loads.  Can anyone help me spot what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Forgot to mention this is in ARC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, *the code you posted* does not create *resizable* images and doesn't call `resizableImageWithCapInsets:`, so the first two leaks are irrelevant to the code. Similarly, the last two leaks happen in `[UIImageView setAnimationImages]`, which *the code you posted* doesn't call. I would see if the leaks are still reported after you deallocate the image view. If the image view is in a reusable table view cell, that might well confuse Instruments. In fact, in that case the animation images could get deallocated only together with the table view itself.

In short, you should look into the relevant methods (by the way, Instruments can also show a stack trace where it thinks the leak happened). The code you posted is absolutely fine, ARC or not.

Comment: Thanks.  I should have mentioned that, too: I never use either method resizableImageWithCapInsets: or setAnimationImages.  I guessed (wrongly I suppose) that my code was using these indirectly.

Comment: Thanks again.  Maybe I should re-ask this way:  do you think I can conclude that, if my app doesn't appear in the responsible library column, that the detected leaks are simulator's leaks and I should ignore them?

Comment: You should examine the leaks' stack traces. It is possible that you leak a UIKit view which uses resizable images internally. However, even if true, it doesn't have anything to do with the code you posted in your question. That code is fine.